# How can I access UISegmentedControl in header of UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, swift2

So this problem is fairly straightforward. I have a `UICollectionViewController` `(MyProfile.swift)` with a header section `(MyProfileHeader.swift)`. Within the latter, I have a `UISegmentedControl` to return different numbers of items AND items in the `collection view cells` (I don't want to initialize an instance of the latter's class within the `UICollectionViewController`). This is my code for `MyProfile.swift class`. I tried adding a target in the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method to return different queries (which works), but I ultimately have to access the segmented control within the `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` methods. The `"testObjects"` and `"writeObjects"` are `array` values that are queried via the `addTarget` method in the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`. I set the `indexPath` but it `returns` an `error` for obvious reasons... How can I access segmented control?

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var numberOfItems: Int? = 0

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyProfileHeader


    if header.userContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        numberOfItems = textObjects.count
    } else if header.userContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        numberOfItems = 0
    } else {
        numberOfItems = photoObjects.count
    }



    print("F: \(numberOfItems!)")
    return numberOfItems!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the header is retrieved for the collection view in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, you can store a weak reference to it in `MyProfile`.

```
class MyProfile: UICollectionViewController {
...
...
weak var header: MyProfileHeader?
...    
...
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyProfileHeader

    return header
}
```

You can then access this from any other function in your `UICollectionViewController`.

Note that `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` can be called before the header has been created in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, so when you access it in `numberOfItemsInSection`, `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, or anywhere else you should check for null and then assume that the segmented control is on the default value (as it will be since this is the first time the view is being displayed). Something like

```
let selectedSegmentIndex = header?.userContent.selectedSegmentIndex ?? 0 //0 is the default value here
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I get the error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: Perhaps you are getting a null when accessing the header because it has not been created yet. I've edited my answer to accommodate this.

Comment: sorry @davedavedave, I have not idea where I would add that code in... would that go in viewDidLoad or...? Also, thanks a lot haha

Comment: I've tried instantiating it in viewDidLoad, but it still doesn't work: header = MyProfileHeader()

Comment: The header is only instantiated in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function - you use the let selectedsegmentIndex... line when you want to access the selected segment from the control. So in your case probably in the numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath functions.

Comment: Yea so it works, but it doesn't recognize the change of the selectedSegmentIndex. It recognizes it's defualt state, but it doesn't respond to events when different segments are selected...

Comment: To respond to changes in selectedSegmentIndex you will need to connect sectionSegementedControlValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) in interface builder and act on that to trigger changes - but this is a different topic from your question here, which I believe has now been answered.

Comment: The outlet needs to be inside the class assigned to the header view, not the collectionview - but again, please ask a different question in this case, don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: I figured it out and I didn't use any of your suggestions. The work around was to create a variable that would change when the segments would change and use that to reload the cells in the collection view

Comment: CAN SOMEONE PLEASE GIVE A CODE EXAMPLE HOW YOU CAN SOLVE IT IM STUCK TO THAT PROBLEM SINCE DAYS

Answer (score 3):

-1st create a `UICollectionReusableView` subclass and name it *SegmentedHeader*

-2nd Inside the *SegmentedHeader* class add a protocol to keep track of which segment was selected. When a segment is selected inside the collectionView's header the protocol/delegate will get passed the value of that segment

-3rd make sure you set the delegate `weak var delegate: SegmentedHeaderDelegate?`

-4th when programmatically creating the `segmentedControl` add a target named *selectedIndex(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)*. When a segment is pressed, you pass the value of that segment to the protocols trackSelectedIndex() function

```
protocol SegmentedHeaderDelegate: class {
    func trackSelectedIndex(_ theSelectedIndex: Int)
}

class SegmentedHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    //MARK:- Programmatic Objects
    let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Zero", "One", "Two"])
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .white
        segmentedControl.isHighlighted = true
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedIndex(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return segmentedControl
    }()

    //MARK:- Class Property
    weak var delegate: SegmentedHeaderDelegate?

    //MARK:- Init Frame
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .white
        setupAnchors()
    }

    //MARK:- TargetAction
    @objc func selectedIndex(_ sender: UISegmentedControl){

        let index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

        switch index {

        case 0: // this means the first segment was chosen
            delegate?.trackSelectedIndex(0)
            break

        case 1: // this means the middle segment was chosen
            delegate?.trackSelectedIndex(1)
            break

        case 2: // this means the last segment was chosen
            delegate?.trackSelectedIndex(2)
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupAnchors(){

        addSubview(segmentedControl)

        segmentedControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Inside the class that has the UICollectionViewController:

IMPORTANT - Make sure you set the delegate inside viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind or none of this will work

```
// MAKE SURE YOU INCLUDE THE SegmentedHeaderDelegate so the class conforms to it
class ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, SegmentedHeaderDelegate{

// add a class property for the header identifier
let segmentedHeaderIdentifier = "segmentedHeader"

// add a class property to keep track of which segment was selected. This gets set inside the tracktSelectedIndex() function. You will need this for cellForRowAtIndexPath so you can show whatever needs to be shown for each segment
var selectedSegment: Int?

// register the SegmentedHeader with the collectionView
collectionView.register(SegmentedHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: segmentedHeaderIdentifier)

// inside the collectionView's delegate below add the header
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        var header: UICollectionReusableView?

        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader{

            let segmentedHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: segmentedHeaderIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SegmentedHeader

            // IMPORTANT >>>>MAKE SURE YOU SET THE DELEGATE or NONE OF THIS WILL WORK<<<<
            segmentedHeader.delegate = self

            // when the scene first appears there won't be any segments chosen so if you want a default one to show until the user picks one then set it here
            // for eg. when the scene first appears the last segment will show
            segmentedHeader.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2

            header = segmentedHeader
        }

        return header!
    }

// inside cellForRowAtIndexPath check the selectedSegmented class property to find out which segment was chosen
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TheCell, for: indexPath) as! TheCell

        // selectedSegment is the class property that gets set inside trackSelectedIndex()
        switch selectedSegment {

            case 0:
            // have the cell display something for the first segment
            break

            case 1:
            // have the cell display something for the middle segment
            break

            case 2:
            // have the cell display something for the last segment
            break

            default:
            break
        }

        return cell
}


// whenever a segment is selected, this delegate function  will get passed the segment's index. It runs a switch statement on theSelectedIndex argument/parameter. Based on that result it will set the selectedIndex class property to match the value from theSelectedIndex argument/parameter
func trackSelectedIndex(_ theSelectedIndex: Int) {

        switch theSelectedIndex {

        case 0: // this means the first segment was chosen
            // set the selectedSegment class property so you can use it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath
            selectedSegment = 0
            print("the selected segment is: \(theSelectedIndex)")
            break

        case 1: // this means the middle segment was chosen
            selectedSegment = 1
            print("the selected segment is: \(theSelectedIndex)")
            break

        case 2: // this means the last segment was chosen
            selectedSegment = 2
            print("the selected segment is: \(theSelectedIndex)")
            break

        default:
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to change the type of cell in cellForItemAt based on the switch statement. Inside each case, I tried to let cell = dequeue a certain Cell. i.e. Case 0: TypeACell, Case 1: TypeBCell; however, it is not working because I am getting no return out of switch statement. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @geistmate you need to dequeue each cell inside the switch statement and make sure to return that same inside that same switch statement. For eg case 0: let cell0 = cv.dequ... return cell0; case 1: let cell1 = cv.dequ... return cell1. You will have to add some cell for the default case

Comment: I've got it working now.. Thank you so much for the quick reply. And sorry last thing, if I would want to change the height of the cell, I also have to place the switch statement within sizeForItemAt as well?

Comment: @geistmate yes, you have to do the same thing and set the size to match the cell using a switch statement the same way you did it in cellForItem

Comment: It's all working perfectly now. I appreciate all the help, thank you. :)

Comment: anytime, Happy Coding!